# Splunk: Why didn't I get another alert email?

Tags: alert, splunk

I configured the following query:

```
someQuery | timechart partial=f span=5m count as numbers | fillnull | streamstats current=f last(numbers) as last_numbers | eval ratio = numbers/last_numbers | where ratio>2.5 OR ratio < 0.5 OR numbers < 51
```

For which I programmed an alert in Splunk. The alert conditions were fullfilled from 03.31 a.m. until 05.45 a.m.

I configured the alert as follows:

The alert type is **scheduled**. It runs on **Cron Schedule**. The Time Range are the **last 12 minutes**. Cron Expression is */10 ****. It expires in **24 hours**. The alert is triggered when the **Number of Results is greater than 0**. Trigger is set to **Once**. Throttle is **checked** and **Supresses triggering for 1 hour(s)**.
When triggered an **email** is sent.

What I would have expected from this configuration is to get an alert email at 03:40 a.m., at 04:40 a.m. and at 05:40 a.m.

What I instead received were mails at 03.40 a.m. (which is expected) and at 05.50 a.m. (what is not expected). I do not understand, what I configured wrong. But I think it is either due to the **throttling** or maybe due to the **time range** of 12 minutes?

Could you tell me what I have to change in order to get the alert mails how I would expect to get them?

Comment: Was there anything that "should" have triggered at either 0440 or 0450? What makes you think you've "missed" something?

Comment: Yes, as written, the alert conditions were triggered for two hours and that was why I expected to get a mail. `numbers` was 0 during all the time between 03.31 a.m and 5.45 a.m. Is there something I configured incorrectly?

Comment: I *suspect* the `Throttle is checked and Supresses triggering for 1 hour(s)` happens to be timing-out past 0440 ...because I *think* it's an hour after the Alert runs, not skipping until whatever otherwise would have been the next hour

Comment: Ok, thanks! But what I do not understand in this case: why did I then get the mail at 05.50 a.m.?

Comment: let me make sure I understand what you said correctly. You expected an Alert at 0340 (ish). Then the Alert suppresses sending for an hour (so it won't send until *after* 0440). Then you next expected an alert at 0550. Because the one you might have expected at 0440 was suppressed. Is that correct? If so, what is the question you have?

Comment: No, not completely correct. The first alert at 0340 was expected (because the alerts are scheduled to run every 10 minutes). The alert condition was triggered the first time at 0340ish. After this the alert conditions were triggered the whole time until 0545. So, I expected to get an alert at 0340, at 0440 or maybe 0450 (because of the suppressing for one hour) and at 0550 (because the alert was triggered the last time at 0545). I do not understand at all why there was no alert mail sent between 0340 and 0550 although the alert was triggered the whole time...

Comment: you also said, *"numbers was 0 during all the time between 03.31 a.m and 5.45 a.m"*. If you had 0 results, why did you expect an Alert to send something? Can you share the Alert herein, and some sample data? Why do you think it would otherwise have sent something during those times? Did you run the search with manual time windows to verify you *should* have gotten something?